# Share gevent locks/semaphores between ThreadPool threads?

Tags: python, gevent

Is there any way to make a lock which can be shared between both greenlets and ThreadPool threads?

Specifically, my application is primarily gevent based, but some portions need to run in a "real" thread… but this causes issues with `logging` handlers, because they use a semaphore around some operations, yielding an exception similar to:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 742, in handle
    self.acquire()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 693, in acquire
    self.lock.acquire()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 128, in acquire
    rc = self.__block.acquire(blocking)
  File "_semaphore.pyx", line 112, in gevent._semaphore.Semaphore.acquire (gevent/gevent._semaphore.c:2984)
  File "…/gevent/hub.py", line 331, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
LoopExit: This operation would block forever
```

This is happening, I suspect, when thread *A* is holding the lock, then thread *B* tries to acquire it. On noticing that the lock is already held, thread *B* tries to `hub.switch()`… but since there is only one greenlet in thread *B*'s `hub`, the "block forever" exception is raised.

So! Is there anything that can be done about this? Or am I stuck?

Comment: I ran into a very similar issue, https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1556 . Would be nice to see a solution for this, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot be sure if this code snipplet is considered pools. But check this out.

All demn point in gevent is that it is asynchronous. For example if you need to request 100 html pages(without gevent). You make first request to first page and your python interpreter is frozen until response is ready. So gevent lets freeze output of those first request and move to second, which means not to waste time.
So we can easily monkey patch all here. But if you need to write results of requests into database ( for example couchdb, couchdb has revisions, which means documents should be modified synchronously). Here we can use Semaphore.

Lets make some damn code ( here is synchronous example):

```
import os
import requests
import time

start = time.time()
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

test_sites = [
    'https://vimeo.com/',
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108576/share-gevent-locks-semaphores-between-threadpool-threads',
    'http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html#gevent.monkey.patch_all',
    'https://www.facebook.com/',
    'https://twitter.com/',
    'https://www.youtube.com/',
    'https://zaxid.net/',
    'https://24tv.ua/',
    'https://zik.ua/',
    'https://github.com/'
]

# request each site and  write request status into file
def process_each_page(html_page):
    # all requests are executed synchronously
    response = requests.get(html_page)
    with open(path + '/results_no_sema.txt', 'a') as results_file:
        results_file.write(str(response.status_code) + ' ' +html_page +'\n')

for page in test_sites:
    process_each_page(page)

print(time.time() - start)
```

Here is analog code with gevent being involved:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import gevent
import os
import requests

from gevent.lock import Semaphore
import time

start = time.time()

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
gevent_lock = Semaphore()

test_sites = [
    'https://vimeo.com/',
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108576/share-gevent-locks-semaphores-between-threadpool-threads',
    'http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html#gevent.monkey.patch_all',
    'https://www.facebook.com/',
    'https://twitter.com/',
    'https://www.youtube.com/',
    'https://zaxid.net/',
    'https://24tv.ua/',
    'https://zik.ua/',
    'https://github.com/'
]

# request each site and  write request status into file
def process_each_page(html_page):
    # here we dont need lock
    response = requests.get(html_page)

    gevent_lock.acquire()
    with open(path + '/results.txt', 'a') as results_file:
        results_file.write(str(response.status_code) + ' ' +html_page +'\n')
    gevent_lock.release()


gevent_greenlets = [gevent.spawn(process_each_page, page) for page in test_sites]
gevent.joinall(gevent_greenlets)
print(time.time() - start)
```

Now lets discover output files. This is from synchronious results.

[image]

And this is from script where gevent was involved.
[image]

As you can see when gevent was used responses came in not in order. So whose response came first was written in file first. The main part lets see what time we saved when gevent was used.

[image]

NOTA-BENE: in example above we dont need to lock writing(append) to file. But for couchdb this is required. So when you use Semaphore with couchdb with get-save documents you get no document Conflicts !